# How to show a message box if a button is pressed more than once in VB?

Tags: vb.net

If I have a button called `BtnPlay` and if the user presses it more than 2 times how do I show a message box?

I tried using a `Select case` statement but this didn't seem to work.

Comment: [Static (Visual Basic)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2cty7t8.aspx).

Comment: You can try declaring the variable PlayNum outside the BtnPlay_Click

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you declare you counter inside the event sub, thus each time the user presses the button, a "new" counter is being created. Declare it outside as a golobal varible and youl be able to do this. Something like that :

```
Public Class Form1

Public PlayNum As Integer = 0

Private Sub BtnPlay_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BtnPlay.Click

    PlayNum = PlayNum + 1
    If PlayNum > 2 Then
        ' Do the stuff you want when the user pressed more than two times.
    Else
        ' Do something else
    End If
End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

The `PlayNum` is reinitialized each time the `BtnPlay_Click` is entered. Therefore either widen the scope of the variable and make it a field of the class ...

```
Public Class Form1
    Private PlayNum As Integer

    Private Sub BtnPlay_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) _
        Handles BtnPlay.Click

        PlayNum += 1
        If PlayNum > 2 Then
            ...
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

... or make it [static](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z2cty7t8.aspx). A static variable retains its value between the calls to this method

```
Private Sub BtnPlay_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) _
    Handles BtnPlay.Click

    Static PlayNum As Integer = 0

    PlayNum += 1
    If PlayNum > 2 Then
        ...
    End If
End Sub
```

Note, the static variable is initialized only once during the lifetime of the object (of type Form1).